# Exception in initializing ApplicationContext HibernateException: Error applying BeanValidation relational constraints

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, bean-validation, spring-bean

I have created earlier [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33213892/error-initializing-applicationcontext-hibernateexception-error-applying-beanval) where i have shave problem it can be temporarily by:

Adding : hibernate.properties : `javax.persistence.validation.mode=none`

I am not able to understand exact reason why it coming this temporarily I am able to fix with : Adding : hibernate.properties : `javax.persistence.validation.mode=none` 
properties. but it can not be final option because Application need to get validate bean.

Can you please help me to understand why it is giving this error earlier this project was working fine:

If I am not putting `javax.persistence.validation.mode=none` properties in `hibernate.properties` i am getting same error.

Please help me to understand and resolve this issue.

My complete stack trace is as below:

```
-  2015-11-13 03:58:51,217 [main] INFO  (support.context.ApplicationContext)   Added 534 mappings (249 configured for L2 cache)
 -  2015-11-13 03:58:51,227 [main] INFO  (support.context.ApplicationContext) Done building hibernate configuration, time 3,201.301 ms
 -  2015-11-13 03:58:51,227 [main] INFO  (support.context.ApplicationContext) Building hibernate session factory
 -  2015-11-13 03:58:51,965 [main] INFO  (connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator) HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: com.hotwg.shared.common.UCPConnectionProvider
 -  2015-11-13 03:58:52,321 [main] INFO  (hibernate.dialect.Dialect) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
 -  2015-11-13 03:58:52,525 [main] FATAL (support.context.ApplicationContext) Error initializing ApplicationContext
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Error applying BeanValidation relational constraints
        at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.applyRelationalConstraints(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:219)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.integrate(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:126)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:302)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1740)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1778)
        at com.hotwg.base.support.context.ApplicationContext.buildSessionFactory(ApplicationContext.java:197)
        at com.hotwg.base.support.context.ContextFactory.buildContext(ContextFactory.java:131)
        at com.hotwg.base.support.context.ContextFactory.buildContext(ContextFactory.java:104)
        at com.hotwg.base.support.context.ContextFactory.createDefaultContext(ContextFactory.java:607)
        at com.hotwg.base.api.batch.StandaloneExecuter.setupContext(StandaloneExecuter.java:334)
        at com.hotwg.base.api.batch.StandaloneExecuter.run(StandaloneExecuter.java:135)
        at com.hotwg.base.api.batch.StandaloneExecuter.main(StandaloneExecuter.java:433)
        at com.hotwg.base.api.batch.AbstractStandaloneRunner.invokeStandaloneExecuter(AbstractStandaloneRunner.java:546)
        at com.hotwg.base.api.batch.ThreadPoolWorker.invokeStandaloneExecuter(ThreadPoolWorker.java:122)
        at com.hotwg.base.api.batch.AbstractStandaloneRunner.run(AbstractStandaloneRunner.java:179)
        at com.hotwg.base.api.batch.ThreadPoolWorker.run(ThreadPoolWorker.java:66)
        at com.hotwg.base.api.batch.ThreadPoolWorker.main(ThreadPoolWorker.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.applyRelationalConstraints(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:208)
        ... 16 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to build the default ValidatorFactory
        at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.getValidatorFactory(TypeSafeActivator.java:524)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.applyDDL(TypeSafeActivator.java:119)
        ... 21 more
Caused by: javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to find a default provider
        at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:264)
        at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:111)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.getValidatorFactory(TypeSafeActivator.java:521)
        ... 22 more
 -  2015-11-13 03:58:52,529 [main] ERROR (api.batch.StandaloneExecuter) error initializing test context
 -  2015-11-13 03:58:52,529 [main] ERROR (api.batch.StandaloneExecuter) Error encountered in standalone executer
com.hotwg.shared.common.LoggedException:
The following stacked messages were reported as the LoggedException was rethrown:
com.hotwg.base.support.context.ContextFactory.createDefaultContext(ContextFactory.java:607): error initializing test context

The root LoggedException was: Error initializing ApplicationContext
        at com.hotwg.shared.common.LoggedException.wrap(LoggedException.java:199)
        at com.hotwg.base.support.context.ApplicationContext.throwUnableToInitializeApplicationContext(ApplicationContext.java:300)
        at com.hotwg.base.support.context.ApplicationContext.buildSessionFactory(ApplicationContext.java:202)
        at com.hotwg.base.support.context.ContextFactory.buildContext(ContextFactory.java:131)
        at com.hotwg.base.support.context.ContextFactory.buildContext(ContextFactory.java:104)
        at com.hotwg.base.support.context.ContextFactory.createDefaultContext(ContextFactory.java:607)
        at com.hotwg.base.api.batch.StandaloneExecuter.setupContext(StandaloneExecuter.java:334)
        at com.hotwg.base.api.batch.StandaloneExecuter.run(StandaloneExecuter.java:135)
        at com.hotwg.base.api.batch.StandaloneExecuter.main(StandaloneExecuter.java:433)
        at com.hotwg.base.api.batch.AbstractStandaloneRunner.invokeStandaloneExecuter(AbstractStandaloneRunner.java:546)
        at com.hotwg.base.api.batch.ThreadPoolWorker.invokeStandaloneExecuter(ThreadPoolWorker.java:122)
        at com.hotwg.base.api.batch.AbstractStandaloneRunner.run(AbstractStandaloneRunner.java:179)
        at com.hotwg.base.api.batch.ThreadPoolWorker.run(ThreadPoolWorker.java:66)
        at com.hotwg.base.api.batch.ThreadPoolWorker.main(ThreadPoolWorker.java:56)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Error applying BeanValidation relational constraints
        at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.applyRelationalConstraints(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:219)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.integrate(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:126)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:302)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1740)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1778)
        at com.hotwg.base.support.context.ApplicationContext.buildSessionFactory(ApplicationContext.java:197)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.applyRelationalConstraints(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:208)
        ... 16 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to build the default ValidatorFactory
        at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.getValidatorFactory(TypeSafeActivator.java:524)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.applyDDL(TypeSafeActivator.java:119)
        ... 21 more
Caused by: javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to find a default provider
        at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:264)
        at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:111)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.getValidatorFactory(TypeSafeActivator.java:521)
        ... 22 more
Exception in thread "main" com.hotwg.shared.common.LoggedException:
The following stacked messages were reported as the LoggedException was rethrown:
com.hotwg.base.support.context.ContextFactory.createDefaultContext(ContextFactory.java:607): error initializing test context

The root LoggedException was: Error initializing ApplicationContext
        at com.hotwg.shared.common.LoggedException.wrap(LoggedException.java:199)
        at com.hotwg.base.support.context.ApplicationContext.throwUnableToInitializeApplicationContext(ApplicationContext.java:300)
        at com.hotwg.base.support.context.ApplicationContext.buildSessionFactory(ApplicationContext.java:202)
        at com.hotwg.base.support.context.ContextFactory.buildContext(ContextFactory.java:131)
        at com.hotwg.base.support.context.ContextFactory.buildContext(ContextFactory.java:104)
        at com.hotwg.base.support.context.ContextFactory.createDefaultContext(ContextFactory.java:607)
        at com.hotwg.base.api.batch.StandaloneExecuter.setupContext(StandaloneExecuter.java:334)
        at com.hotwg.base.api.batch.StandaloneExecuter.run(StandaloneExecuter.java:135)
        at com.hotwg.base.api.batch.StandaloneExecuter.main(StandaloneExecuter.java:433)
        at com.hotwg.base.api.batch.AbstractStandaloneRunner.invokeStandaloneExecuter(AbstractStandaloneRunner.java:546)
        at com.hotwg.base.api.batch.ThreadPoolWorker.invokeStandaloneExecuter(ThreadPoolWorker.java:122)
        at com.hotwg.base.api.batch.AbstractStandaloneRunner.run(AbstractStandaloneRunner.java:179)
        at com.hotwg.base.api.batch.ThreadPoolWorker.run(ThreadPoolWorker.java:66)
        at com.hotwg.base.api.batch.ThreadPoolWorker.main(ThreadPoolWorker.java:56)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Error applying BeanValidation relational constraints
        at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.applyRelationalConstraints(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:219)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.integrate(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:126)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:302)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1740)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1778)
        at com.hotwg.base.support.context.ApplicationContext.buildSessionFactory(ApplicationContext.java:197)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.applyRelationalConstraints(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:208)
        ... 16 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to build the default ValidatorFactory
        at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.getValidatorFactory(TypeSafeActivator.java:524)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.applyDDL(TypeSafeActivator.java:119)
        ... 21 more
Caused by: javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to find a default provider
        at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:264)
        at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:111)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.getValidatorFactory(TypeSafeActivator.java:521)
        ... 22 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure I understand your question completely, but if the problem is that you get the above stacktrace when you bootstrap your application and it disappears when you set `javax.persistence.validation.mode=none`, then the answer is the following.

Setting the validation mode tells ORM, or more specifically the [BeanValidationIntegrator](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/cfg/beanvalidation/BeanValidationIntegrator.java) to not enable Bean Validation at all. This is per JPA spec where the behavior between JPA and Bean Validation is specified.

In any other mode the `BeanValidationIntegrator` will try to enable Bean Validation. It checks whether `javax.validation.Validation` is on the classpath taking this as a key to bootstrap Bean Validation. However, it also requires that there is a Bean Validation implementation available, for example Hibernate Validator.

Your stacktrace implies that you have the Bean Validation API on the classpath, but no Bean Validation Provider (implementation).

How do your dependencies look like?

Comment: I have a hard time seeing the connection here. SSL is about encrypting TCP/IP traffic. There is no connection whatsoever to Bean Validation. There must be more going on here. I would assume you have problems with your overall project setup, but you have neither provided any details regarding the context in which Bean Validation is used nor any details about which version(s) of framework(s) are at play.

Comment: To answer your Q-"How do your dependencies look like?"
I have complete set of  hibernet4.1 jars in my Class path and dependency with Weblogic related jars.

Answer (score 0):

In my application we are using hibernate 4 and after adding **hibernate-validator-4.1.0.Final.jar** to classpath I am not getting this exceptoin even though I am not having this properties in  hibernate.properties : `javax.persistence.validation.mode=none`

I am able to resolved this by adding **hibernate-validator-4.1.0.Final.jar** in application classpath.

Comment: wlfullclient.jar will have javax.validation.Validation class included and this implicitly. It triggers the Bean Validation class to bootstrap validation. 

Hence now adding the hibernate-validation-XX.jar fixes it.The wlfullclient.jar.
If we will not include the javax.validaton.Validation Class in wlfullclient.jar. It will resolved. I have checked in my class path wlfullclient.jar  is also present.